# Detectar conexión y desconexión de un dispositivo con puerto serial en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema con una validación, primero hago la PC detecte si cierto dispositivo USB esta conectado por medio de su HardwareID, eso sale correctamente. Pero cuando intento hacer lo mismo con una impresora por medio del puerto serial, la detecta como siempre activa aunque ya la haya desconectado. Esto es lo que tengo en mi método para el dispositivo serial:

```
         int iResultado = -5;
         ManagementObjectSearcher searcher1 =
                new ManagementObjectSearcher( "root\\CIMV2" ,
                "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Caption IS NOT NULL" );

            foreach ( ManagementObject queryObj in searcher1.Get( ) )
            {

                if ( queryObj["Caption"].ToString( ).Contains( "(COM" ) )
                {
                    List<string> DevInfo = new List<string>( );

                    string Caption = queryObj["Caption"].ToString( );
                    int CaptionIndex = Caption.IndexOf( "(COM" );
                    string CaptionInfo = Caption.Substring( CaptionIndex + 1 ).TrimEnd( ')' ); // make the trimming more correct                


                    string deviceId = queryObj["deviceid"].ToString( ); //"DeviceID"

                    int vidIndex = deviceId.IndexOf( "ACPI" );


                    if ( vidIndex != -1 )
                    {
                        if ( deviceId.Contains( "PNP0501" ) )
                        {
                            sPortName = CaptionInfo;
                            iResultado = 0;
                            ConsoleWriteLine("La impresora esta conectada: " + iResultado);
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                            Console.WriteLine("La impresora no esta en linea: " + iResultado);
                    }
                }
            }
```

¿Existe alguna propiedad para saber si estos dispositivos seriales están disponibles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para puertos seriales lo mejor es tratarlo con la clase SerialPort:

He aquí un ejemplo:

```
SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
//Evento para capturar errores de recepción
sp.ErrorReceived += Sp_ErrorReceived;
//Evento para capturar recepcion de datos
sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Sp_DataReceived);
//abrir el puerto serial
sp.Open();

//Método recepción de datos
private void Sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   //datos recibidos del puerto serial.
   var data = sp.ReadExisting();
}

private void Sp_ErrorReceived(object sender, SerialErrorReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
    //Aqui va el código que quieras desarrollar en caso de fallos de conexión.
}
```